# Partition didn't reflect the changes after increasing OS Disk Size in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, disk-space-utilization, parted

I have a Ubuntu VM which has an unmanaged OS disk associated with it.

When we increased the size of the unmanaged OS disk from 30 GB to 50 GB(after deallocating the VM and increasing its size from the platform), the changes are not reflected in the filesystem /dev/sda1 and it is continuing to show the size of the partition to be 30 GB.

The increased 20 GB is shown as a free space when I RDP my VM.

Could anyone please help me with increasing the size of /dev/sda1 filesystem to 50 GB?

Answer (score 1):

When you increase the disk size in Azure all you are doing is increasing the size of the underlying disk, you are not doing anything in OS to have it use that extra space.

Now you have a larger disk attached to your VM you need to have your OS use it. You can use the ResizePart on Linux to do this. There is an article from Microsoft on exactly how to do this [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/expand-disks).